How to get the total file size of all files uploaded by a user?
For a specific user, how could I determine the total amount of space used for all files uploaded by that user?  This assumes that the uploaded files can include:

File fields on entities
Image media entities (I guess you could include this in "File fields on entities")
User pictures

Ultimate goal: Restrict users to uploading no more than 500 MB of files.

One way to do this (especially if you haven't launched your site and do not yet have user data) is to carefully structure the upload directories so that all user-uploaded files are put in a directory structure that looks like:
base directory for uploads -> user id (or uuid) -> images, user_picture, etc.
Then all you have to do is get the file size of the upload directory for that user.
